# Use double quotes in batch string

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch script that changes a line in one of my files.

text.file:

```
ex1
ex2
<"ex3">
ex4
```

I want to replace `<"ex3">` with `<"ex5">`.  I am currently using this code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

rename text.file text.tmp
for /f %%a in (text.tmp) do (
    set foo=%%a
    if !foo!=="<"ex3">" set foo="<"ex5">"
    echo !foo! >> text.file) 
del text.tmp
```

How do I escape `"` so that I can compare the string with the value in `foo`?  I have tried using `\"`, `^"`, and `""`.  With the first two, I get `The syntax of the command is incorrect`, and with the last one nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

rename text.file text.tmp
for /f %%a in (text.tmp) do (
    set foo=%%a
    if "!foo!"=="<"ex3">" set "foo=<"ex5">"
    echo !foo! >> text.file) 
del text.tmp
```